# Set equality involving supremum of functions

Tags: measure-theory

Consider a sequence of measurable functions $f_n$.

I would like to know if the following statements are true or false.
For a positive number $c$,
\begin{align}\{\sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} |f_n|>c\} = \cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\{|f_n|>c\},\end{align}
and
$$\{\sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} |f_n|\leq c\} = \cap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\{|f_n|\leq c\},$$

The inclusions $\supset$ in the first one and $\subset$ in the second are easy. How about the other direction?

And for $\supset$ in the second one, I argue as the following,

$x \in \cap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\{|f_n|\leq c\}\implies \forall n: |f_n|\leq c$
and by taking supremum equality proved. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes your argument for $\supset$ in the second one is correct. As explained below, $|f_n|\le c$ for all $n$ implies $\sup_n |f_n|\le c$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first one, $\subset$:

Let $L=\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} |f_n(x)|$. Assume $L<\infty$. By the definition of $\sup$, for all $\epsilon>0$ there is $n$ such that $L-|f_n(x)|<\epsilon$ (it is the *smallest* upper bound). That is, $|f_n(x)|>L-\epsilon$. Now let $\epsilon=L-c>0$. Then $|f_n(x)|>L-\epsilon=c$.

If $L=\infty$, then $|f_n(x)|$ is an unbounded sequence, that is it will eventually exceed $c$. So there exists $n$ such that $|f_n(x)|>c$.

The second one, $\supset$:

Suppose $|f_n(x)|\le c$ for all $n$. That is, $c$ is an upper bound for the $|f_n(x)|$. Then by the definition of the supremum being the smallest upper bound, we must have $\sup_n |f_n(x)|\le c$.

Comment: What if $L = \infty$? Does it mean $\forall M<\infty, \exists n_0: \quad |f_{n_0}| = M$?

Comment: @newbie: Good point, if $L=\infty$, then $|f_n|$ is unbounded, so it will eventually also exceed $c$.